# Issues with importing kubernetes to terraform

Tags: azure, kubernetes, import, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

When trying to import our existing Kubernetes cluster config to the Terraform state file, it fails with

```
Error: flattening `default_node_pool`: The Default Agent Pool "" was not found
```

I can't see how I can import the default node pool, which is *part* of the cluster configuration, separateley. Any hints someone?

> Terraform v0.13.5
>
> - provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v2.23.0
> - provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random v3.0.0

This is the part of my TF code that defines the cluster (anonymized and variables resolved):

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "k8seu" {
    name                = "aks-dev-west"
    location            = "westeurope"
    resource_group_name = "my-rg"
    dns_prefix          = "dns-aks-dev"
    kubernetes_version  = "1.18.10"

    linux_profile {
        admin_username = "ubuntu"
        ssh_key {
            key_data = "ssh-rsa ...<key-hash>...=="
        }
    }

    default_node_pool {
        name                = "mydevnp"
        node_count          = 1
        vm_size             = "Standard_D2_v2"
        type                = "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
        availability_zones  = ["1","2","3"]
        vnet_subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.mysubnet.id
    }

    service_principal {
        client_id     = "...<hash-for-client-id>..."
        client_secret = "...<hash-with-client-secret>..."
    }
    windows_profile {
        admin_username = "azureuser"
        admin_password = "mywonderfulpassword"
    }
    addon_profile {
        kube_dashboard {
            enabled = true
        }
        oms_agent {
            enabled                    = true
            log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.mylog.id
        }
    }
    network_profile {
        network_plugin      = "azure"
        service_cidr        = "10.0.3.0/27"
        dns_service_ip      = "10.0.3.10"
        docker_bridge_cidr  = "172.17.0.1/16"
        load_balancer_sku   = "standard"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the code as well

Comment: In which step you get the error? Apply the script?

Comment: No, as I wrote, I'm trying to _import_ the existing configuration.

Comment: I mean you got the error in the import step or when you apply the Terraform script?

Comment: I get in in the import step